# How to create multiple zip files and move them into a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple script that creates a bunch of zip files from my inputs.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Declare directories to backup"
read dir_list
for dir in $dir_list
do
    name="${dir}.tbz"
    tar --create --verbose bzip2 --file=$name $dir
done
```

I then tried adding a move command to move them into a directory by adding this line in my for loop...

```
do
    name="${dir}.tbz"
    tar --create --verbose bzip2 --file=$name $dir
    mv $name ~/backups
done
```

But i end up getting a Bzip archive file called backups. Instead i was hoping to have a folder named backups with all the .tbz files i just created.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Nit -- more common extension for a bzip2 compressed archive is `.tar.bz2`, though `.tbz` (or any other name you want to give it) is fine -- just may cause some file-recognition issues in some file-managers, that classify by extension.

Comment: I don't see in your code any attempt to create a zip file. You only seem to create `tar` archives. You **can** use `tar` to automatically zip the tar, but you don't do this. Have a look at the `tar` options `-I`, `-z` and `-J`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkdir -p "$HOME/backups"` above the loop — you have to create the directory first. The `-p` flag is to create parent directories if they don't exist, but also serves to avoid failure if ~/backups already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't create the directory. you have to create it. best command is mkdir -p.
if the directory exists, you have to use mv $name ~/backups/ in your loop.
also you can run the script in backups directory and enter the relative or absolute address of main files.